# Installed wordpress blog from development environment does not work

Tags: wordpress

I've installed a wordpress blog on my development environment. The URL for this environment is `dev.mysite.com` and my live environment is located at `mysite.com`. They both share the same database. There's an SVN that works on both environments.

I've installed the wordpress blog on my development environment and everything is fine, but when I moved to the real environment it does not open.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_optionsLIMIT 1000
```

The query above shows, that the **siteurl** is `dev.mysite.com`. I can change it, but then it will stop working on the development environment (right?). Is there any way to be able to access the blog from both environments, while sharing the same database?

Answer (score 1):

In short I think the answer is no.
Wordpress stores the site/base URL in a few rows in that wp_options table, so it will only work properly for one URL. Is there a reason you need to point them both to the same DB?

When I'm working on Wordpress I just work on the one dev environment and then update my live site incrementally. I thought that was the reason you would have separate environments!

Comment: I've added a comment on Dmitry Scriptin's answer, that will answer some of your questions

Comment: You could set up a local server within the office and back the production server up on to it, then use it as the development database though. You can use any computer as a server, even your own. Others in the office can point their development machines at your hosted database then instead of the live one...

Answer (score 1):

It is a VERY BAD IDEA to use same DB for both development and production, because you can accidently break it (always have backups!). You should have separate DBs, and the one for production should only be used by production app.

You better use some build tools to update production automatically if you need it often, or at least do it manually. Consider using [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) or another build tools.

Comment: I know it's a bad idea to use the same DB. It's out of my authorities to change that at this moment. We're using amazon cloud and the DB is a seperate server and at this time we cannot buy another one for some reasons. I'm looking for a workaround now. Our company will change this architecture and add a second DB server soon.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I can suggect making a set of tables with different prefixes in the same DB just for development. In that case you can have slightly more separated environments.